# Trouble Getting Browser Extension to Control Playback Speed of Facebook Videos

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

**Description:**

I'm developing a browser extension with the sole purpose of adjusting the playback speed of videos on Facebook pages. The extension functions flawlessly on other websites, however, I've hit a roadblock when trying to implement it specifically on Facebook.

**Problem:**

When I apply the extension to Facebook videos, the speed adjustment doesn't seem to take effect.

**My code:**

[image]

popup.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fb Video Speed Control</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Facebook Video Speed Control</h2>
  <form id="speedForm">
    <label for="speed">Playback Speed:</label>
    <input type="number" id="speed" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="5" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Apply</button>
  </form>
  
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Fb Video Speed Control",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Adjust Facebook video playback speed",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
    "icons": {
      "48": "icon.png"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "48": "icon.png"
      }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("Popup DOMContentLoaded event fired."); 

  const form = document.getElementById("speedForm");
  const speedInput = document.getElementById("speed");

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const selectedSpeed = parseFloat(speedInput.value);
    console.log("Submit button clicked. Selected speed:", selectedSpeed); 
    chrome.storage.local.set({ playbackSpeed: selectedSpeed }, function() {
      console.log("Playback speed set to:", selectedSpeed); 
    });
  });
});
```

content.js :

```
console.log("Content script is running."); 

chrome.storage.local.get(["playbackSpeed"], function(result) {
  const playbackSpeed = result.playbackSpeed || 1;
  console.log("Playback speed retrieved:", playbackSpeed); 
  const videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].playbackRate = playbackSpeed;
    console.log("Video", i, "playback speed set to:", playbackSpeed); 
  }
});
```

**Request:**

I'm reaching out to seek advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this specific issue. If anyone has experience with creating browser extensions that interact with Facebook's environment, your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that modern SPA sites (**s**ingle-**p**age **a**pplication) like facebook generate the contents of the page dynamically, whereas the initial contents loaded from server is just an empty template with a header/footer. Your content.js runs on this empty page and doesn't find any videos, then their script generates the content asynchronously based on a new network request.

**The most lightweight solution is to listen to `play` event:**

```js
const STORAGE = chrome.storage.sync; // `sync` is preferable for small settings
const KEY = 'playbackSpeed';
const ignored = new WeakSet();
let speed, speedPromise;
addEventListener('play', async e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'VIDEO' && !ignored.has(e.target)) {
    ignored.add(e.target);
    e.target.playbackRate = speed || await (
      speedPromise || (speedPromise = STORAGE.get(KEY).then(r => (speed = r[KEY])))
    );
  }
}, true); // IMPORTANT! The `play` event doesn't bubble, so we listen in the first phase

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(changes => {
  const ch = changes[KEY];
  if (ch) {
    speed = ch.newValue;
    for (const el of document.getElementsByTagName('video')) {
      el.playbackRate = speed;
    }
  }
});
```

Another solution is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which you can use to detect the video elements being added, but it's wasteful because not all of them will be played.

Comment: I hope you're well. I implemented your solution in my content.js for adjusting playback speed. When I load the extension, I encounter an error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to set the 'playbackRate' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite."

I followed your advice to troubleshoot, but I'm uncertain about the cause. Can you guide me to address this as a beginner?

Comment: Use a breakpoint or console.log. The most likely reason is that the value is empty, in which case you can use `||1` fallback.